# apply nested within lapply not working in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

just earlier today I received a very helpful answer for a problem I was running into that allowed me to move onto the next step of one of my projects. However, I got stuck again later on in the project, and I'm wondering if any of you can help me move forward.

## Context

Currently, I have a list of data frames that are full of soccer matches called `wc_match_dataframes`. Here is what one of the data frames looks like:

```
type_id tourn_id day month year team_A   score_A score_B team_B   win     loss
f       wc_1934  27  5     1934 Germany  5       2       Belgium  Germany Belgium
```

I wasn't able to fit the data for the final three columns, `draw`, `drawA`, and `drawB` but basically the `draw` column is `TRUE` if the match is a draw, if not, it is `FALSE`. In the case of a draw, the win and loss columns are just filled by `Draw`. The `drawA` column is filled by `team_A` if the match was a draw, and likewise, the `drawB` column is filled by `team_B`.

The `type_id` is either `f` or `q` depending on if the match was a World Cup qualifier or a World Cup finals match. The `tourn_id` refers to the tournament the match was for, whether it was a qualifier or finals.

There are a total of 39 of these data frames, with a "finals" data frame for each of the 20 World Cup tournaments, and a "qualifiers" data frame for 19 tournaments (the first World Cup did not have qualifying).

## What I Want To Do

I'm trying to populate a different list of data frames `wc_dataframes` with data for each of the 20 World Cups at the country level as opposed to the match level. Each of these twenty data frames will have the countries that made it to the finals of said  tournament and their data like so:

1. Country
2. Wins in qualifying
3. Wins in finals
4. Losses in qualifying
5. Losses in finals

... and so on.

I have been able to populate the first `country` column for every World Cup no problem, but I'm running into issues for the rest of the columns.

## Here is what I'm doing

This is the unlooped (only works for one World Cup) version of my code that works successfully:

```
wc_dataframes$wc_1930$fw  <- apply(wc_dataframes$wc_1930, MARGIN = 1, function(country)
                         sum(wc_match_dataframes$`wc_1930 f`$w == country, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This is successfully populating the finals win column in the `wc_dataframes$wc_1930` data frame by counting the number of wins.

Now, when I try and nest this under lapply to do it across all World Cup years like so:

```
lapply(names(wc_dataframes), function(year)
      wc_dataframes$year$fw  <- apply(wc_dataframes$year, MARGIN = 1, function(country)
        sum(wc_match_dataframes$`year f`$w == country, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

It does not work for me. I suspect that the issue has to do with defining the `year` function and running into issues in the `sum` portion of my code. I come from a background in STATA so I am more used to running `for` loops and what not. I'm still getting used to R and lists and everything so I really appreciate the help.

### Thank you!

Thank you so much in advance for the help, and happy holidays! :)

Comment: (1) It'd be helpful if you can provide enough example data to run your code on, along with the exact expected output.  (2) "Here is what one of the data frames looks like:" <- Does this mean each of the `wc_match_dataframes ` data frames has exactly one row?  (3) Have you considered `dplyr`?

Comment: Are you missing curly braces for the functional argument to the `lapply`?

Comment: The way you are using the variable `year` in your `lapply` function is incorrect. You really should post a functioning example. You need something like `wc_dataframes[[year]]$fw <- apply(wc_dataframes[[year]]...`. The way you have it written is not using the `year` passed by the lapply, but the variable `year` in the `wc_dataframes` object, which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to output whatever you have replaced:

```
lapply(names(wc_dataframes), function(year){
  wc_dataframes[[year]]$fw  <- apply(wc_dataframes[[year]], MARGIN = 1, function(country)
    sum(wc_match_dataframes[[paste(year,'f')]]$w == country, na.rm = TRUE));
  wc_dataframes}
  )
```